# Gmail doesn't work with default Mail app on iPhone 6 with data only

Tags: iphone, gmail, mobile-mail

Like any normal person, I've hooked up my Gmail account to the default Mail app on iPhone 6. But for some reason it's not sending or receiving anything when I'm on data (Verizon 4G LTE), while working perfectly on wifi. I've tried my Outlook account also which works pretty much fine except for problems with sending on occasion.

On data trying to refresh inbox, I get a popup saying: "The mail server 'imap.gmail.com' is not responding. Verify that you have the entered the correct account info in Mail settings." On data trying to send, I get a popup saying: "The connection to the outgoing server 'smtp.gmail.com' failed. Additional Outgoing Mail Servers can be configured in Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars." Started noticing about a week ago. Anyone know if this is a known bug of some sort, or at least fixable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was resolved in a comment which has since been removed. The solution was to enable data for the mail app, because I had previously turned it off.